Experiencing weird behavior with animation using Framer motion and Nextjs 14 for a portfolio website
I am developing a simple portfolio website for myself using Typescript, Nextjs 14 and tailwind and for animations, I went with framer motion. To display, all my projects I wanted in a mobile view, I wanted to display them in an image carousel style way. I wrote this simple project_cards.tsx file which would switch between desktop view and mobile view. The desktop view works fine since I am not using framer motion there, but in mobile view, it behaves weirdly.

I posted a gif so its easier to visualize the issue. As you can see, whenever I click next, the whole box moves up and out of the view and then you have to swipe down to see the view again.
In my project, I call the project cards here
<Box className="w-screen h-full fixed border-4 border-red-600 block">
                <ProjectCards />
              </Box>

And the everything is defined in project cards
import {
  Alert,
  AlertIcon,
  AlertTitle,
  Box,
  Button,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardFooter,
  CardHeader,
  Heading,
  Show,
  Text,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { InView } from "react-intersection-observer";
import { projects } from "../../../public/project_content.json";

interface project_data {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  overview: string;
  summary: string;
  demo: string;
  github: string;
}

function ProjectCards() {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState("left");

  const handleNext = () => {
    setDirection("right");
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) =>
      prevIndex + 1 === projects.length ? 0 : prevIndex + 1
    );
  };
  const handlePrevious = () => {
    setDirection("left");
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) =>
      prevIndex - 1 < 0 ? projects.length - 1 : prevIndex - 1
    );
  };
  const handleDotClick = (index: number) => {
    setCurrentIndex(index);
  };
  const slideVariants = {
    hiddenRight: {
      x: "110%",
      opacity: 0,
    },
    hiddenLeft: {
      x: "-110%",
      opacity: 0,
    },
    visible: {
      x: "0",
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        duration: 1.5,
      },
    },
    exit: {
      opacity: 0,
      scale: 0.4,
      transition: {
        duration: 0.5,
      },
    },
  };

  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  return (
    <>
      <Box className="border-2 border-white grid grid-cols-2 justify-center items-center m-auto grid-flow-row grid-rows-2 w-full">
        <Show breakpoint="(min-width: 800px)">
          {projects.map((project: project_data, index: number) => (
            <InView key={index}>
              {({ inView, ref }) => (
                <Card
                  ref={ref}
                  key={project.id}
                  className={
                    inView
                      ? "w-auto bg-glass backdrop-blur-lg text-white transform scale-100 duration-1000 m-10 rounded-xl animate-slide-in-left p-20 border-2 border-glassBorder shadow-glassShadow xl:w-9/12 grid grid-cols-3 grid-rows-2 grid-flow-row"
                      : "bg-black text-white transform scale-0 duration-300"
                  }
                >
                  <CardHeader className="h-20 w-full justify-center items-center max-sm:text-sm col-span-full border-2 border-red-600 mb-5">
                    <Heading className="text-2xl text-white text-mono xl:text-6xl justify-center items-center">
                      {project.name}
                    </Heading>
                  </CardHeader>
                  <CardBody className="h-full mb-20 text-xl xl:text-5xl row-span-1 border-2 border-red-600 xl:text-pretty xl:font-extralight">
                    <Text>{project.overview}</Text>
                  </CardBody>
                  <CardFooter className="w-full h-1.5 justify-between items-center p-[10px] xl:h-1/2 border-2 border-red-600">
                    <Button
                      onClick={() => window.open(project.demo)}
                      className="w-auto bg-white text-black p-[10px] rounded-md border-0 font-mono -translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 hover:bg-black hover:text-white duration-300 xl:text-3xl text-xl"
                    >
                      Demo
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                      className="w-auto bg-white text-black p-[10px] rounded-md border-0 font-mono -translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 hover:bg-black hover:text-white duration-300 xl:text-3xl text-xl"
                      onClick={() => window.open(project.github)}
                    >
                      Github
                    </Button>
                  </CardFooter>
                </Card>
              )}
            </InView>
          ))}
        </Show>
      </Box>
      <Show breakpoint="(max-width: 480px)">
        <Box className="w-full h-full inline-flex flex-col items-center justify-cente">
          <Box className="relative h-full w-full">
            <AnimatePresence>
              <motion.div
                key={currentIndex}
                variants={slideVariants}
                initial={direction === "right" ? "hiddenRight" : "hiddenLeft"}
                animate="visible"
                exit="exit"
                className="w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center"
              >
                <Card className="bg-glass backdrop-blur-lg shadow-glassShadow text-white m-10 rounded-xl p-10">
                  <CardHeader className="h-1/5 w-full justify-center items-center top-0">
                    <Heading className="text-2xl text-white text-mono">
                      {projects[currentIndex].name}
                    </Heading>
                  </CardHeader>
                  <CardBody className="w-full h-full mb-20">
                    <Text>{projects[currentIndex].overview}</Text>
                  </CardBody>
                  <CardFooter className=" w-full h-1.5 justify-between items-center p-[10px]">
                    <Button
                      onClick={() => {
                        if (projects[currentIndex].demo !== "N/A") {
                          window.open(projects[currentIndex].demo);
                        } else {
                          <Alert
                            status="error"
                            className="z-10 flex relative w-full h-auto"
                          >
                            <AlertIcon />
                            <AlertTitle>Demo Not Avaible</AlertTitle>
                          </Alert>;
                        }
                      }}
                      className="w-40 bg-white text-black p-[10px] rounded-md border-0 font-mono -translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 hover:bg-black hover:text-white duration-300 mr-[15px]"
                    >
                      Demo
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                      className="w-40 bg-white text-black p-[10px] rounded-md border-0 font-mono -translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 hover:bg-black hover:text-white duration-300 ml-[15px]"
                      onClick={() => window.open(projects[currentIndex].github)}
                    >
                      Github
                    </Button>
                  </CardFooter>
                </Card>
              </motion.div>
            </AnimatePresence>
          </Box>
          <Box className="mt-[12px]">
            <Button
              onClick={() => handlePrevious()}
              className="px-8 py-2 rounded-md bg-teal-500 text-white font-bold transition duration-200 hover:bg-white hover:text-black border-2 border-transparent hover:border-teal-500 mr-40"
            >
              Prev
            </Button>
            <Button
              className="px-8 py-2 rounded-md bg-teal-500 text-white font-bold transition duration-200 hover:bg-white hover:text-black border-2 border-transparent hover:border-teal-500"
              onClick={() => handleNext()}
            >
              Next
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Show>
    </>
  );
}

export default ProjectCards;

I can't seem to pinpoint whats causing this behavior, I tried to make the <Box's position fixed but that did not help.
